# Twisted - listen to multiple ports for multiple processes with one reactor

Tags: python, process, twisted

i need to run multiple instances of my server app each on it's own port. It's not a problem if i start these with os.system or subprocess.Popen, but i'd like to have some process communication with multiprocessing.

I'd like to somehow dynamically set up listening to different port from different processes. Just calling reactor.listenTCP doesn't do it, because i getting strange Errno 22 while stopping reactor. I'm also pretty sure it's not the correct way to do it. I looked for examples, but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks Tzury, it's kinda what i'd like to get. But i have to dynamicly add ports to listen. For Example

```
from twisted.internet import reactor 
from multiprocessing import Process 

def addListener(self, port, site): 
    ''' Called when I have to add new port to listen to. 
    site - factory handling input, NevowSite in my case''' 
    p = Process(target=f, args=(port, func)) 
    p.start() 

def f(self, port, func): 
    ''' Runs as a new process''' 
    reactor.listenTCP(port, func)
```

I need a way to neatly stop such processes. Just calling reactor.stop() stop a child process doesn't do it.

This is the error i'm gettin when i trying to stop a process

```
    --- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/share/exe/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 755, in doRead
    skt, addr = self.socket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 195, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
<class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Dimitri.

Comment: Well, actually, it is the correct way to do things. You can have as many different servers listening an different ports in a single reactor as you like... The whole point of the reactor thing is, that you have only a single one. So, what do you do in your Protocol implementations?

Comment: I bind ports to NevowSite-instances (hope thats what you ment). 

What than should i do to "unlisten" reactor from the ports? Do i have to stop the reactor bevor i add new ports to listen? Is it a problem, that i do it from different processes? 

Sorry for all the questions, but i really can't find a tutorial or comprehensible documentation on this matter.

Comment: Why are you starting multiple processes ? Twisted is designed to work with only one reactor in a single process.

Comment: In fact, calling `listenTCP` should just do it.  If you are still interested in the answer to this question, it would be helpful if you could supply the sample code that causes the "Error 22".

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure what error you are getting.
The following is an example from [twisted site](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/servers.html) (modified)
And as you can see, it listen on two ports, and can listen to many more.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class QOTD(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("An apple a day keeps the doctor away\r\n") 
        self.transport.loseConnection()

# Next lines are magic:
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = QOTD

# 8007 is the port you want to run under. Choose something >1024
reactor.listenTCP(8007, factory)
reactor.listenTCP(8008, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: wow it's over a decade later: will this answer work for me?  let's see